# Angular UI Bootstrap time & date pickers popus shown underneath inputs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

**picker problem SOLVED, but still not working together with animated classes**
I'm experiencing problems with showing **Angular-strap or UI Bootstrap time & date** pickers. It is shown underneath the input elements, that are on the table rows underneath and I have no clue what to do with it anymore, tried various z-index, position, display css, but no luck.

here is an image of how it looks:

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA7o8.png (sry for url, too low reputation to post it here)

I have no custom classes that would affect it, using bootstrap.

my css for the inputs to override bootstrap's css, but no difference if I comment it.

```
#content select, input, label, textarea, input[type="date"], input[type="time"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="month"] {
max-width: 99% !important;
width: 99% ;
line-height:normal !important;
}
input.input-normal {
max-width: auto !important;
width: auto;
height: auto;
line-height:inherit !important;
}
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

**EDIT:**
The problem disappeared when I removed supporting classes for ngAnimate on the table row. Here is CSS that does it:

```
.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't look like a index issue more like missing background... but difficult to say without seeing if possible please share link to  the page or a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of relative/absolute placement.

The best way to deal with that is to change the container where it's triggered at. Try something like this inside your html tag where you define the element:

```
container="body"
```

This should make sure that it's above everything else. Instead of body you can use other elements as well, but that one should work fine, unless you're in a modal.